# Your favorite lesser-known Rails gems/plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

What are your favorite lesser-known gems/plugins for Rails?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538600/what-rails-plugins-are-good-stable-and-really-enhance-your-code) about Rails plugins brought up only the usual suspects (Paperclip, RSpec, Shoulda, Restful Auth, etc). It'd be great to get a list going about the hidden, less popular ones that rock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just started using [App_Version](http://github.com/toland/app_version/tree/master). It's nice to be able to put the version of the app that your running on the bottom of your page (Like the "svn revision" number on the bottom right-hand corner of this page).

Comment: Ahh good suggestion, I could see this coming in handy.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [cache_money](http://github.com/nkallen/cache-money/tree/master) a lot in projects recently. Its given us a huge performance increase

Answer (score 4):

I'm really liking [delayed_job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/tree/master) for asynchronous tasks it's simple and effective.  Been using it for async mail with great success.

Answer (score 2):

Another one i've found I'm using more and more is [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/), this gives you guarded method invocation.

Instead of

```
entry.at('description') && entry.at('description').inner_text
```

you write

```
entry.at('description').andand.inner_text
```

It's been saving my fingers lots of typing in the last couple of projects.

Comment: Current versions of rails have .try(:method)

Answer (score 1):

[Dr. Nic's Magic Models](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/) Not that i actually use this gem on any of my projects, I just thought it was cool when it was first released. Dr. Nic also did a hack so if you made typos in your code it would guess what you meant, so very very wrong.. but funny as hell.

Comment: Check the video of him showing it off: http://drnicwilliams.com/2007/03/22/meta-magic-in-ruby-presentation/

Answer (score 1):

[responds_to _parent](http://github.com/markcatley/responds_to_parent/tree/master) lets you do ajax-like things with file upload forms (which can't use real ajax.) But you can also use it anytime you want to send RJS to the parent window.

Also, a bit of self-promotion. I really like my plugin [soundex_find](http://github.com/waltjones/soundex_find/tree/master), which allows you to handle misspellings and phonetic matches in auto-completers or searches.

Comment: soundex_find is nice, btw. good job with that.

Comment: Thanks, it's my first open source contribution since leaving a very non-oss company.  I plan to continue to get involved in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think Summarize (https://github.com/ssoper/summarize) and Geocoder (http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) are pretty cool.